# jinja2: default layout

Tags: python, layout, jinja2

Suppose this is my code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

def render(path, **kwargs):
  env = Environment()
  env.loader = PackageLoader('lemma.app.views', '')
  template = env.get_template(path)

  return str(template.render(**kwargs))
```

And it is my template:

```
{% extends "layouts/application.html" %}

{% block content %}
  bla
{% endblock %}
```

Is there way to set layout in my code, not in my template, or should I write `{% extends "layouts/application.html" %}` in every template like an idiot?

Comment: Seems like you already answered your own question.

Comment: You can subclass Environment and add a "parent" parameter to the get_template method concatenating the {% extends %} declaration. Or subclass PackageLoader, whatever rocks your boat.

Comment: BTW, look at [jinja2.BaseLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.BaseLoader), you can override the get_source method in order to automatically insert the {% extends %} tag. It is a good question anyway, upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've defined class `LemmaLoader` inherited from `PackageLoader`, and have overrided method `get_source`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in the extends of the child template : {% extends layout %}.
This makes it easy to change your base / layout template and makes it possible to select another base / layout template. I use extends variables because for different layout templates for the same child. The child template is part of a webpage or part of a fancybox iframe.